# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type jsonb[] to jsonb

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have a schema that goes like the following

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(max_length=120,primary_key=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    delivery_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    order_Desc= ArrayField(JSONField(),default=list, null=True);
    order_by = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE);
```

I was initially trying to set a list of JSON objects into the order description columns but was constantly facing an issue  `column "order_Desc" is of type jsonb[] but expression is of type text[]` while model object create. So I tried to convert `order_Desc= ArrayField(JSONField(),default=list, null=True);` to `order_Desc= JSONField(blank =True,null=True)` but I get the following error while migrating

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type jsonb[] to jsonb
LINE 1: ...TER COLUMN "order_Desc" TYPE jsonb USING "order_Desc"::jsonb
```

I am not sure what to do. I tried reverting back to the old state but somehow I still get the same issue which was weird. I also tried adding a new column to the model of type JSONField keeping the old state as it was but this error never seem to go. Thank for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get an error while migrating it means that the migration did not pass, and so you don't need to revert it; just remove the generated migration file.